# How do you insert ordinal indicators in a content control date picker?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

How do you insert ordinal indicators into date picker content controls that will show the date like:

`26th day of October, 2016`

I've tried `d \*ordinal 'day of' MMMM, yyyy` but using `\*ordinal` doesn't work in content controls like it works in date fields.

Can you use ordinal indicators in the date picker content control?

Answer (score 2):

> Can you use ordinal indicators in the date picker content control?

Yes, but not in the way you have mentioned. In newer versions of MS Word, it is not possible to use `d \*ordinal 'day of' MMMM, yyyy` as it was possible to use in date fields. Because the date format MS Word will accept is `DATE [\@ "Date-Time Picture"] [Switches]` where `Date-Time Picture` is the formatting like `dd mm yyyy` and `Switches` are the formatting options like `\*ordinal`.

So, at a time single Date-Time Picture and a single Switch is possible to include in a date format. This problem can be solved by using `VBA` script but that is somewhat not so handy.

The simple way to solve this problem is to use multiple numbers of content controls placing side by side. So, in your case you have to take two content controls of date as follows:

`{DATE \@ "d"\*Ordinal}` `{DATE \@ "'day of' MMMM, yyyy"}`

Comment: I can't make this work with the date picker, what's the trick?

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a nested field of your desired date format

   ```
   {DATE \@ "'{DATE \@ d \*Ordinal} day of' MMMM, yyyy"}
   ```

   You may follow the following steps:

   1.1. Hit `Ctrl-F9` to insert a blank field, inside `{}`, enter:

   ```
      DATE \@ "' day of' MMMM, yyyy"
   ```

   1.2. Move the I-cursor to where between the opening single quote and " `day`"

   1.3. Hit Ctrl-F9 again to insert another blank field, inside `{}` enter:

   ```
      DATE \@ d \*Ordinal
   ```

   1.4 Hit F9 to refresh the field
2. Add the built block to your Quick Parts Gallery

   2.1. Double-click to highlight your nested field

   2.2. Select tab Insert from the Ribbon, click icon Quick Parts then Save Selection to Quick Parts Gallery.

   2.3. Give a name to the nested field e.g. "Boss needed Date", then click OK.
3. To use the date, click Quick Parts. The "Boss needed Date" is here.

As you may know, you can replace `DATE` with `CREATEDATE, PRINDATE, SAVEDATE or DOCPROPERTY MyCustomDate`.

Hope that you'd find it helpful.

Comment: But, the nested field you have mentioned in no. 1 is not correct as I have tested. It shows output like:

`{DATE @ d *Ordinal} day of December, 2016`

Comment: Do not simply enter { }. Hit Ctrl-F9.

Comment: Ctrl-F9 works. But, if I am not wrong by entering nested field the nested field becomes static. I mean, say today is 29th December. So, if I use the fields like you have mentioned then the output apparently looks ok but it is not. You can test it by re-editing the field. As I have found it says:

`{ DATE \@ "29th day of' MMMM, yyyy" }`

So, the nested field you used is no longer there. That means, when it is 30th December, then the date will remain 29th.

Comment: Because you did not actually test it. Don't use your right click to toggle just the outer field. Hit Alt-F9 to show all your field codes in your document. Moreover, Word does not automatically refresh all field codes by default, always Ctrl-A then F9 after opening a saved document. I see that you have provided a good enough answer. But there're still many things you can learn from others.